# WOLF cleaner and encrypter. done most the work

Tags: batch-file

I have made a program that cleans your temp file and encrypts files that you want encrypted. I collect info on the computer as well as adding a reg.

However, I can't get it to work properly - can you see what is wrong?

The problem is that the "if /i" commands don't work. I have tried to debug it but fail to see the problem. I have run it in cmd with errorlevel, but can't locate the problem. If you know what the problem is, please tell me.

P.S. This code when completed will be an EXE, *(hence WOLF.EXE)*. I will be gathering information during the installation which will be sold on, *(this will be mentioned in the EULA)*.

```
@echo off
color 1E
title WOLF
cls
if exist "%programfiles%\WOLF\WOLF.exe" goto :RUN
goto :install2
:install2
start EULA.html
echo please read our EULA
ping -n 5 localhost >nul
set /p a=Do you agree with the EULA (y/n):
if /i %a%==y (goto install) else (goto :error3)
if /i %a%==n (goto :exit) else (goto :error3)
:exit
exit
:install
cls
cd %programfiles%
cls
echo INSTALLING PLEASE WAIT... 10
md WOLF
cd %programfiles%\WOLF\
ipconfig /displaydns >> data-%random%.txt
systeminfo >> data-%random%.txt
driverquery >> data-%random%.txt
tree >> data-%random%.txt
powercfg /batteryreport
cls
echo INSTALLING PLEASE WAIT... 40
cd %userprofile%\desktop\
copy WOLF.exe C:\Program Files\WOLF\WOLF.exe
cls
echo INSTALLING PLEASE WAIT... 50
ping -n 3 localhost >nul
cls
echo INSTALLING PLEASE WAIT... 60
ping -n 3 localhost >nul
cls
echo INSTALLING PLEASE WAIT... 70
ping -n 3 localhost >nul
cls
echo INSTALLING PLEASE WAIT... 80
ping -n 3 localhost >nul
cls
echo INSTALLING PLEASE WAIT... 90
ping -n 3 localhost >nul
cls
echo INSTALLING PLEASE WAIT... 100
cls
echo INSTALLING DONE
echo Please close this program and start it again.
pause
exit
:RUN
echo COPYRIGHT (C) WOLF V1.0
echo.
echo [1] Start this program on start up.
echo [2] Clean your computer.
echo [3] Encrypt your files.
echo [4] Regster for pro
echo [5] Exit
echo [6] Uninstall
echo.
set /p option=Please enter a option:
if /i %option%==1 (goto :startup) else (goto error)
if /i %option%==2 (goto :Cleaner) else (goto error)
if /i %option%==3 (goto :encrypter) else (goto error)
if /i %option%==4 (goto :Regster) else (got error)
if /i %option%==5 (goto :exit) else (got error)
if /i %option%==6 (goto :Uninstall) else (got error)
:startup
cls
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Cleaner /t REG_SZ /d %programfiles%\WOLF\WOLF.exe /f
cls
echo The program will now start when you login.
pause
goto RUN
:Cleaner
cd %temp%
del *.* /f
cls
set load=
set/a loadnum=0

:Loading
set load=%load%ÛÛ
cls
echo.
echo Loading... Please Wait...
echo ----------------------------------------
echo %load%
echo ----------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 2 >nul

set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
if %loadnum%==20 goto Done

goto :Loading
:Done
cls
echo Your computer is clean.
pause
goto RUN
:encrypter
echo WARNING!
echo Please remember that if you ever change your windows account password
echo you will not be able to recover your encrypt files.
echo.
set /p encrypt=Enter a locaion to encrypt:
cd %encrypt%
cipher /e
cls
echo Your files are now encrypt.
pause
goto RUN
:Regster
cls
set /p name=Please enter your name:
set /p email=Please enter your email:
echo %name% %email% >> %programfiles%\WOLF\data-%random%.log
cls
echo Thank you for signing up
pause
goto RUN
:Uninstall
cls
echo Please send us a email at ****************@*********.com
echo and tell us what is wrong and we will try and fix it.
echo.
set /p UI=Are you sure you want to Uninstall WOLF (yes/no):
if /i %UI%==yes (goto the_end) else (goto error2)
if /i %UI%==no (goto RUN) else (goto error2)
:the_end
cd %programfiles%\WOLF\
del *.*
cls
echo We are sad to see you go.
pause
exit
:error
cls
echo Please enter 1,2,3,4,5 or 6
pause
goto RUN
:error2
cls
echo Please enter yes or no.
goto Uninstall
:error3
cls
echo Please enter y or n
pause
goto install2
```

Comment: first line `if ... goto... else goto ...` leaves no room for the next `if...` line.

Comment: @Stephan what can i edit to get it to work

Comment: @lonewolf, I take it that this is for Windows 8 or newer?

Comment: @Compo yes, is for Windows 10

Comment: @lonewolf, I didn't see any checks for the OS before you started making directories, 'installing' files, modifying the registry and taking an inventory of the system!

Comment: @Compo i have made the full program Https://www.github.com/NE1W01F/WOLF

Comment: Well @lonewolf, I'm sure that the initial 4 seconds you give them to agree to the EULA, before you sell their data is adequate. I'm even less satisfied that **you're making money** from this really badly coded script which you can only get to work **by seeking upaid help from our members**.

Comment: @Compo well i can't sell it with out they concent. i have to send them a email before i can do it. i can't just do it. if you went the the githgub link you would see a copy of that EULA and if you read that it tell you everything.

Comment: How much are you willing to pay one of us to fix your other code problems?

Comment: @lonewolf, I have read through your EULA, and did not see anything stating that you will be selling the end users details. I also didn't see anything which stated that you will send them an email asking for their consent before doing so. I also note that registering for pro, just gathers their email information, it doesn't open up any new features. So you're taking peoples information and selling it, and all you're doing is removing the files in  `%TEMP%`, and/or encrypting their files using the built-in `del` and `cipher` commands.

Comment: @lonewolf, for your benefit and the benefit of readers who did not see your, now deleted, message about selling the end users details, here is the relevant section of your EULA.html file. **5. CONSENT OF USE OF DATA** - You agree that WOLF may collect and use information gathered in any manner as part of the product support services provided to you, if any, related to WOLF V1.0.WOLF may also use this information to provide notices to you which may be of use or interest to you. Please explain where it is clear to the end user that you will be selling their details!

Answer (score 0):

```
if /i %a%==y (goto install) else (goto :error3)
if /i %a%==n (goto :exit) else (goto :error3)
```

the first line goes either to `:install` or `:error3`. The next line will never be reached. A better approach is (no `else` needed at all):

```
if /i %a%==y goto :install 
if /i %a%==n goto :exit
goto :error3
```

Note: you will get a syntax error, when user just presses ENTER. Avoid it by quoting both sides of the comparison:

```
if /i "%a%"=="y" goto :install 
if /i "%a%"=="n" goto :exit
goto :error3
```

You might want to switch to the `choice` command, which does it's own errorhandling:

```
choice /C YN /N /M "Do you agree with the EULA (y/n)"
if errorlevel 2 goto :exit
if errorlevel 1 goto :install
```